# Discrete MOSFET Amplifier question: Trouble finding the Overdrive Voltage

Tags: voltage, mosfet, amplifier

I am working on an exercise problem (5.18) regarding Discrete MOSFET Amplifiers. I have taken pictures of the question material (Disregard the section under the question) and my latest attempt at a solution:

[image: The question]

[image: The given circuit]

Alright. Keep in mind that the circuit above is from a different question, they are just re-using it in this one, but they changed the value of V<sub>DD</sub> from +15V to +5V. Also, they remove R<sub>L</sub>, but I don't think that matters for my specific issue.

Now, I decided to begin with a DC Analysis to find V<sub>OV</sub> (Overdrive voltage). I know that I can replace the capacitors with open circuits and then use the MOSFET Saturation current equation and KVL for another current equation, equate them, then solve the resulting quadratic.

**However, this method yields an answer different from the book. The book provides V<sub>OV</sub> = 0.319V, whereas I get V<sub>OV</sub> = 0.83V.**

**Is my approach correct? I'm pretty sure the math is sound, so I'm not really sure how to proceed. My solution:**

[image: My solution part 1]

[image: My solution part 2]

Comment: I love those "infinite" capacitors. Obviously, they denote "arbitrarily large" and are meant just for DC blocking, but in fact, an infinite capacitor is indistinguishable from a short circuit!

Comment: @DaveTweed, to be sure, an "infinite" capacitance capacitor is indistinguishable from an ideal voltage source (and a 0V ideal voltage source is indeed indistinguishable from an ideal short circuit).  In fact, once one has the DC solution, replacing a coupling cap with an ideal voltage source of voltage equal to the DC voltage across the cap gives the same result as having infinite capacitance.

Comment: I want a font made from your handwriting.

Comment: Haha! Are you kidding it looks horrible! :P

Comment: Thanks though :) Getting a good pen really helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are misinterpreting the question.

The question is asking you to design the circuit to meet certain specs, which includes choosing the drain resistor Rd. In your analysis, you are assuming that Rd is 10kohms. The answer states that Rd is 78.5kohms.

Comment: Wow! I can't believe I misread the question! Thank you so much, I'm going to figure out my next approach now :D

Comment: Alright, I went through the question and answered it completely! Thanks again for your help! :)